# Mapping a DTO to an EF entity Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, dto

I have an application to apply for jobs. Once an applicant fills out all of the information and submits the application, I want to save it. Currently I have a component to save each piece of the application as it relates to the data model (personal info, availability, etc). When I run it, I get an exception that states:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
>
> ## For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>
> CandidateDto -> Candidate (Destination member list)
>   EmploymentApplication.Common.DataTransferObjects.CandidateDto -> EmploymentApplication.Entities.Candidate (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties:
>   AddressId
>   CandidateApplications
>   CandidateAvailabilities
>   CandidateEducations
>   CandidateEmploymentHistories
>   CandidateReferences
>   CandidateTeleLicenses

I have tried to specify the AddressId in a MapFrom statement and for the rest, they are just EF navigation properties that in the mapping initialization I said to ignore. Unfortunately, the error persists and I don't know what to do now.

Here is a look at my mappings:

```
        Mapper.Initialize(m => m.CreateMap<Candidate, CandidateDto>());
        Mapper.Initialize(m => m.CreateMap<CandidateDto, Candidate>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AddressId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address.AddressId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CandidateApplications, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CandidateAvailabilities, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CandidateEducations, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CandidateEmploymentHistories, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CandidateReferences, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CandidateTeleLicenses, opt => opt.Ignore())
        );
```

Here is the component method where the Mapping actually occurs:

```
        public void SaveCandidateInfo(CandidateDto candidateDto)
    {
        var candidateInfoToAdd = _mapper.Map<Candidate>(candidateDto);
        _candidateRepository.Add(candidateInfoToAdd);
        _candidateRepository.Save();
    }
```

Here is the DTO:

```
    public class CandidateDto
{
    public Guid CandidateId { get; set; }
    public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
    public UserAccountDto UserAccount { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryPhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool HasWorkEligibility { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid UserAccountId { get; set; }
}
```

And lastly, here is EF class for a candidate:

```
 public partial class Candidate
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Candidate()
    {
        this.CandidateApplications = new HashSet<CandidateApplication>();
        this.CandidateAvailabilities = new HashSet<CandidateAvailability>();
        this.CandidateEducations = new HashSet<CandidateEducation>();
        this.CandidateEmploymentHistories = new HashSet<CandidateEmploymentHistory>();
        this.CandidateReferences = new HashSet<CandidateReference>();
        this.CandidateTeleLicenses = new HashSet<CandidateTeleLicense>();
    }

    public System.Guid CandidateId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> AddressId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryPhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool HasWorkEligibility { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserAccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CandidateApplication> CandidateApplications { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CandidateAvailability> CandidateAvailabilities { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CandidateEducation> CandidateEducations { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CandidateEmploymentHistory> CandidateEmploymentHistories { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CandidateReference> CandidateReferences { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CandidateTeleLicense> CandidateTeleLicenses { get; set; }
    public virtual UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You configuration looks backwards. You have `CreateMap<CandidateDto, Candidate>()` but you do `.ForMember(dest => dest.AddressId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address.AddressId))`. Which says `CanditateDto` has an `Address` property. And you only need one Initialize.

Comment: Doesn't candidateDto have an address property?

Comment: What AM version are you using? Also can you provide full repro (a.k.a. [mcve])

Comment: AutoMapper Version 6.2.2. I'll add the repos now.

Comment: Never figured it out so I just decided to manually map them in the method that saves the data. Not the prettiest approach I know, but I didn't know what else to do.

Comment: Mapper.Initialize should be only called once per AppDomain. This throws in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You defined some configurations about destination properties to ignore them but when you are trying to map it, there is no destination instance which should be passed the `Map` method. So, there is no matter about ignored properties.

So, you should change it;

```
var candidateInfoToAdd = _mapper.Map<Candidate>(candidateDto);
```

to

```
var candidateInfoToAdd = new Candidate();
_mapper.Map<CandidateDto,Candidate>(candidateDto, candidateInfoToAdd);
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but get the same original exception at run time.